# Reverse proxy function

Tags: security, reverse-proxy

Question about how a reverse proxy appears to the requester:

If I have a secure web app running on a port lets say 9443 and a customer who due to corporate IT restriction can not access it and I use a reverse proxy to act as a DMZ and forward 443 traffic to 9443. Will the customer be able to access the web app.

Please assume that changing the app on port 9443 is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like apache/nginx to proxy your requests from a DMZ to the backend application server running on that port.  You just need to make sure the ports are open from the DMZ to the LAN where the appserver is.

Comment: sure assuming everything is working and configured properly, it's a theoretical question about how reverse proxies work.